# Either or constraint WITH ONE POINT IN COMMON in linear programming operations-research

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

suppose we have a quantity variable x (which is upperbounded by n), and a logic variable y which is equal to

y = 1 if x >= s; where s is a generic number

y = 0 otherwise => if x is strictly lesser than s => if x < s

Surfing around on the internet I found out this clear explanation https://youtu.be/iQ3PlKKorXA?t=35 which turned out to be the common pattern about either-or constraint. Therefore following the video, the solution would be:

s - x <= (1 - y)*n

x - s <= y*n

And yet x could be equal to s in both the cases.

How can we fix this?

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for you for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the following two constraints:

```
x-s ≤ My - ɛ(1-y) 
s-x ≤ M(1-y)
```

where `M` is a sufficiently large upper bound and `ɛ` is a small positive constant.

The first enforce the logical constraint `if x >= s then y = 1` and the second the constraint `if x < s then y = 0`.

Note that these are often referred to as indicator constraints and are supported by several solvers (e.g., [cplex](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.9.0?topic=optimization-indicator-constraints-in)) with advantages in terms of a more numerically stable model.

Comment: thk for your answer. Can you link some references?

Comment: btw I was looking for sth more theoretical instead of using machine precision de facto. Machine precision could vary from architecture to architecture therefore the result is not unique

Comment: @Matteo In practice, there are feasibility tolerances involved. So talking about machine precision is just not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

With many solvers you can use logical constraints.

For example with CPLEX OPL you can write

```
int s=3;
dvar int x;
dvar boolean y;

subject to
{
  y==(x>=s);
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer, but that wasn't my point. My concern is not about how to write it on a solver. I'd like a full mathematical answer, Obviously `y==(x>=s)` is not in mathematical language

Comment: first we declare a unique mathematic way which doesn't rely on eps due to finite arithmetic (take a look at the answer above)